# Issues with functions in django

Tags: python, django, function, django-views

I am new to django. and I have made a small project in it which is working good.

Now what I want is I have made some functions in my view.py file now I wants to call these functions in some other file say a.py. So how I can do that, anybody have some idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `a.py` do:

```
from views import function1, function2

def a_function_one():
   ...
   #call function1 from views
   function1()
```

Comment: Yes It works
Actually  I did that previously...but it gives the error no arguments given .......... So gave some arguments and it works..........Thanks for your interest